# getting error while running oozie

Tags: hadoop, extjs, oozie

i am getting the following error while running the following oozie command

hadoop@master1:~/work/oozie-4.1.0/bin$ **oozie-setup.sh -hadoop 0.20.200 $HADOOP_HOME -extjs /home/hadoop/work/ext-2.2.zip**

setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"

Usage  : oozie-setup.sh

prepare-war [-d directory] [-secure] (-d identifies an alternative directory

for processing jars
                                                -secure will configure the war file to use HTTPS (SSL))

sharelib create -fs FS_URI [-locallib SHARED_LIBRARY] (create sharelib for

oozie,
                                                                FS_URI is the fs.default.name
                                                                for hdfs uri; SHARED_LIBRARY, path to the
                                                                Oozie sharelib to install, it can be a tarball
                                                                or an expanded version of it. If ommited,
                                                                the Oozie sharelib tarball from the Oozie
                                                                installation directory will be used)
                                                                (action failes if sharelib is already installed
                                                                in HDFS)

sharelib upgrade -fs FS_URI [-locallib SHARED_LIBRARY] (upgrade existing

sharelib, fails if there
                                                                  is no existing sharelib installed in HDFS)
          db create|upgrade|postupgrade -run [-sqlfile ] (create, upgrade or postupgrade oozie db with an
                                                                optional sql File)
          (without options prints this usage information)

EXTJS can be downloaded from http://www.extjs.com/learn/Ext_Version_Archives

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXT.js iw for WEBUI right,
It shows the we need to Prepare war that means need to add the EXT.js by passing the command

```
oozie-setup.sh prepare-war
```

or by

```
addtowar.sh -extjs EXTJS_PATH
```

Make sure that the ext.js file was present in the LIBEXT in the oozie home while using preparewar.

Reference:
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/AG_Install.html#Oozie_Server_Setup